# Finding the mountpoint of an device in shell scripts

Tags: big-sur, plist, zsh

Looking for a **correct** and simple way to find a mountpoint in a shell script.

This working as expected

```
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/my.XXXXXX)
mpoint=$(diskutil info -plist disk1s1 >"$tmp" ; /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print MountPoint' "$tmp")
rm -f "$tmp"
```

but it needs a temporary file.

While it isn't a big deal, but still would be *nicer* to do it without of the `tempfile`.

Unfortunately, the

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print MountPoint' <(diskutil info -plist disk1s1)
```

doesn't works.

It is a bug of the `PlistBuddy` or I missed something?

Using `zsh` in fresh `Big Sur` installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `here string` to pass the output of `diskutil` to standard in.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :MountPoint" /dev/stdin <<< "$(diskutil info -plist disk1s1)"
```

Comment: Very **wild** construction, but working... :D thanx :D

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of `PlistBuddy` that it can only read from a file, not from a pipe. Contructs like `… | /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /dev/stdin` and `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /dev/stdin <(…)` use a pipe to plug the output of `…` into the input of `PlistBuddy`. You need to use a temporary file. But you can have the shell do it for you. [Here-documents and here-strings](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirection) use a temporary file, as does zsh's `=(…)` [process substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print MountPoint' <<EOF
$(diskutil info -plist disk1s1)
EOF
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print MountPoint' <<<$(diskutil info -plist disk1s1)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print MountPoint' =(diskutil info -plist disk1s1)
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may be able to get mount point information from `df` instead.

```
df -P |awk '$1 == "/dev/disk1s1" {print $6}'
```

(Note that this simple version does not handle mount point paths containing spaces correctly.)

Comment: The first two `PlistBuddy` commands doesn't works at all (prints `Usage:....` error text). The last one (with the `=(` ) runs OK. Parsing output of the `df` aren't universal, for example, your command will fail if the mountpoint path containing a space, like `/Path/To Mount/Point` The `diskutil` outputting plist-xml will have always the correct value. Thank you anyway for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution without PlistBuddy would be:

`diskutil info /dev/disk1s1 | awk '/Mount Point:/{print substr($0, index($0,$3))}'`

The solution with `df` allegedly gets messed up, if you have a whitespace in your path, as @clt60 wrote above, so you would need something like

`df -P | awk '$1 == "/dev/disk1s1" {print substr($0, index($0,$6))}'`

Comment: `diskutil info /dev/disk1s1 | awk '/Mount Point:/{$1=$2="";$0=$0;$1=$1;print}'`

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution, with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652496/107090):

```
diskutil info /dev/disk1s1 | awk '/Mount Point:/{$1=$2="";$0=$0;$1=$1;print}
```

The trick is to force awk to reparse the fields after deleting the first two fields.